# Winter damper setting for humidifiers

Tags: furnace, humidifier

Problem: My brother has a drum humidifier on his furnace and is quite satisfied with it, so I installed one on my furnace this fall. He claims it is a good idea to partially close the damper for winter operation - he says, "if the damper is open all the way, the furnace has to run longer to heat the house because so much hot air is being sent into the cold air duct." I don't know if I agree with him, but perhaps I don't understand what he is driving at. All the information and instructions I can find only talk about "open" and "closed" positions.

Question: Can anyone comment about partially closing dampers for humidifier operation for winter?

Comment: Details, please. Describe your installation with more clarity or post a photo.

Answer (score 1):

The damper should be wide open since the wall or duct mounted humidistat (that should have been installed) controls the operation of the humidifier and how much humidity is introduced into the living space. You are right not to agree with your brother since he is not correct. If you have A/C then you close the damper in the summer, otherwise leave it open.

Don't forget that most drum type humidifiers need cleaned at least once a year. I have a drum humidifier and soak the media pad in a bucket filled with vinegar and clean the reservoir pan as well. My humidifier also has a drain to flush the reservoir numerous times during the winter.